# What is the correct use of the word "abuses"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, differences, slang

What is the correct use of the word "abuses"?

While the phrase: "Human rights abuses" doesn't seem incorrect, "verbal and physical abuses" does. I am tired, so if I'm being dense please don't be too harsh. I can't seem to find anything that will explain this satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

Abuses can serve as either a noun or verb.

`"Human rights abuses"` works if this is a noun-phrase such that 'abuses' is used as a noun. As a verb, you do not need the inflectional `"-s"` as this is incompatible with a plural noun.

You could say `"Human rights abuses are generally frowned upon in democratic societies."` but not `"Human rights abuses people in a negative way."`. One thing I would say, particularly regarding the former, is that a three-part compound noun can make for rather difficult reading and can become rather ambiguous, and although not 'wrong', it is quite stylistically poor if avoidable. Of course if you're referring to some jargon e.g. some chemical name or the construction is simply avoidable then it can be okay, but generally try to avoid using more than two components in a, particularly open, compound noun.

The same is the case for `"verbal and physical abuses"`.

Comment: Did you mean to say "unavoidable" (not avoidable) in the third line from the bottom in your third paragraph?  Out of curiosity, I wonder what a phrase with a "chemical name" would look like.  Have an example?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `"unavoidable"`. And an example of a compound noun that is a chemical name is: `"Picket Fence Porphyrin"`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatically correct examples of [*noun adjucts*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

The only reason '*human rights abuses*' seems more correct is because you're used to hearing that phrase, but there's nothing wrong with the other phrase.